# How to get correct date after conversion from String to date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am converting Date from String type Date to Date type Date,using SimpleDateFormat but the
resulting date I am getting is getting changed.can anyone tell me why its changing
Also **what should i use to get the correct Date type date from String** and not the changed one as I am getting here.

```
    Date d = null;
    String startTime="2012-03-17 16:00:00 PM";
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
    try {
          d=  sdf.parse(startTime);
         } catch (ParseException e) {}

System.out.println("DD="+d) //printing Sun Mar 18 04:00:00 IST 2012 ? why this 
   //Date enterd was 17 Mar 2012
```

Comment: I'm surprised that works at all, given that you're using `hh` (in the range 1-12) with a value of 16.

Comment: You specified the AM/PM cycle. Which is based on 12 hours, not 24.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It's not really surprising. `DateFormat` is by default operating with a "lenient" Calendar, so that overflowing a field will cause the next more significant field to be incremented while trying to get the set field within the valid range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ambigous if you combine a 24h clock and an AM/PM marker. In your case you should either use "HH" (capital H) to parse the hour field in the range 0-23 and ignore the AM/PM suffix or use a 12h-clock with appropriate AM/PM suffix (in your case "04:00:00 PM").

Answer (score 2):

### You have got a wrong Date-Time string as the input.

AM/PM marker is not applicable for the 24-Hour format of time. It should be either  `2012-03-17 04:00:00 PM` or `2012-03-17 16:00:00`.

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

Let's first try to do it the way you have done:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String startDateTime = "2012-03-17 16:00:00 PM";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(startDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
> Text '2012-03-17 16:00:00 PM' could not be parsed: Invalid value for
> ClockHourOfAmPm (valid values 1 - 12): 16

As you can see, the `java.time` API correctly throws an exception informing you about the problem. `SimpleDateFormat`, on the other hand, parses the input string erroneously.

Now, let's see how you can parse it correctly. In order to parse it correctly, we will use:

1. The format, `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` where `H` specifies the 24-Hour format. For your Date-Time string, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).
2. The function, [`DateTimeFormatter#parse(CharSequence, ParsePosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.text.ParsePosition-) with the `ParsePosition` index set to `0`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String startDateTime = "2012-03-17 16:00:00 PM";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.from(dtf.parse(startDateTime, pp));
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2012-03-17T16:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/vq0SDI)

**Note:** [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`16:00:00 PM` is not a valid time and `SimpleDateFormat` will convert it to the next day at 4:00am.

Comment: He has to use "HH" instead of "hh" for a 24h-clock as well.

Comment: +1, Or start time of "2012-03-17 4:00:00 PM" with the original format

Answer (score 1):

You're using `hh` in your format string, which is a 12-hour format. That makes sense, given that you've got an AM/PM designator (`a`) as well... but it *doesn't* make sense for a value of 16.

I suspect at that "16 o'clock pm" is translating to 4am the following day, hence the problem. (Oddly enough, using `setLenient(false)` *doesn't* pick up this error.)

*Either* use a format of `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` and make sure you haven't got " PM" at the end, *or* use your existing format but give it sensible values (04 instead of 16).

Additionally, I would suggest:

- Using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) is generally a good idea for date/time work in Java
- *Don't* swallow `ParseException` like this. Empty catch blocks are a really bad idea.
- When you call `Date.toString()` that always uses the default time zone, and you can't change the output format. That's okay sometimes, for quick diagnostics, but it can give a misleading impression that the `Date` actually has time zone information, when it doesn't.